# Cannot Start Sonarqube Server with the latest Version

Tags: java, process, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Facing Java process launcher error while starting Sonar server. 
Please note that we are have used Sonarqube-4.5.7, sonarqube-5.0.1, Sonarqube 5.6 and JDK 7,8 combinations . but still no luck

below is the log :

```
2016.06.20 18:31:24 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\swmuthuk\Documents\sonarqube-5.0.1\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\swmuthuk\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process2908084003470791693properties
2016.06.20 18:31:25 INFO  sea[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2016.06.20 18:31:25 INFO  sea[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2016.06.20 18:31:25 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1466427684530] version[1.1.2], pid[4912], build[e511f7b/2014-05-22T12:27:39Z]
2016.06.20 18:31:25 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1466427684530] initializing ...
2016.06.20 18:31:25 INFO  sea[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1466427684530] loaded [], sites []
2016.06.20 18:31:27 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1466427684530] initialized
2016.06.20 18:31:27 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1466427684530] starting ...
2016.06.20 18:31:27 WARN  sea[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Fail to start search
org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9001]
```

Comment: The problem is "Failed to bind to [9001]". Check if there is already a port active.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve the issue. Issue is the port assigned could be used by any other process. Hence you could not bind that port. To use the free port. follow the below :

In ../conf/sonar.properties, Assign 0 to sonar.search.port and remove #. Save the file and start the sonar again

Answer (score 3):

You already have a process bound to the 9001 port, most probably an Elastic Search from a previous SonarQube set up, and that was not stopped properly.
Search for that process id, kill it, and then start SonarQube again, it should work.

Comment: i tried checking for this process id. but there is not PID corresponding to this.. And i also have tried starting sonar from another machine, still the same error and wrapper stopped with out starting sonar

Comment: I'm not sure if the search server "2016.06.20 18:31:25 INFO  sea[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
" and the "elasticsearch" process are the same. The elasticsearch start will fail as the search server uses the same port before.